Detecting a large horizontal band in the center of an image
I have a small (228x228) grayscale image that I have created by segmenting the original image and converting it to grayscale after applying colors to the segment. I want to know possible approaches I can take to detecting the large band in the image. Here is the image I'm working with:

I don't understand why it looks so faint on StackOverflow, as it looks fine in my Jupyter Notebook.
I know that the large band for this image and other images I will be working with will always be roughly horizontal and fairly straight. I tried an approach using eccentricity detection, but that seems to fail.
Any help would be appreciated!
